# SAP Vora dealing with decimal type

Tags: sap-bw, vora

So I'm trying to create and load Vora table from an ORC file created by SAP BW archiving process on HDFS.

The Hive table automatically generated on top of that file by BW has, among other things, this column:

```
archreqtsn decimal(23,0)
```

At attempt to create a Vora table using that datatype fails with the error

> Unsupported type (DecimalType(23,0)}) on column archreqtsn

So, the biggest decimal supported seems to be decimal(18,0)?

Next thing I tried was to either use decimal(18,0) or string as the type for that column. But when attempting to load data from a file:

```
APPEND TABLE F002_5_F 
OPTIONS  (
files "/sap/bw/hb3/nldata/o_1ebic_1ef002__5/act/archpartid=p20170611052758000009000/000000_0",
format "orc" )
```

I'm getting another error:

> com.sap.spark.vora.client.VoraClientException: Could not load table F002_5_F: [Vora [.com.au:30932.1639407]] sap.hanavora.jdbc.VoraException: HL(9): Runtime error. (decimal 128 unsupported (c++ exception)).
>
> An unsuccessful attempt to load a table might lead to an inconsistent table state. Please drop the table and re-create it if necessary. with error code 0, status ERROR_STATUS

What could be the workarounds for this issue of unsupported decimal types?

In fact, I might not need that column in the Vora table at all, but I can't get rid of it in the ORC file.

Comment: In the Hadoop ecosystem, `DECIMAL` is wrapped over the Java `BigDecimal` type, but it appears that VORA uses a C++ library. Now it's complicated: the ORC documentation does **not** mention `DECIMAL` as a standard data type, cf. https://orc.apache.org/docs/types.html. But the ORC C++ library has classes named `Decimal64ColumnReader` and `Decimal128ColumnReader` to handle `DECIMAL` type (plus some code for the legacy Hive 0.11 concept of "DECIMAL") cf. https://github.com/apache/orc/blob/master/c%2B%2B/src/ColumnReader.cc. So my guess is that's a **SAP bug** and you should open a support ticket.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter I'll try Vora 1.4, as it seems to have some bugfixes related to handling decimal.

Comment: Vora versions up to Vora 2.0 support only decimal up to precision 18. It is planned to increase the maximum precision in future Vora versions (subject to change).